# Set Neumann Boundary Condition in NDEigensystem function

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I want to get the eigenvalue and the eigenfunction of the following partial differential equation:
$$ -(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2})\psi_n (x,y) + [\frac{1}{4}(x^2+y^2) + 0.1 x^2 y^2 ]\psi_n (x,y) = E_n \psi_n (x,y) $$

The boundary condition is Neumann boundary condition. However, I don't know how to set this boundary condition in `NDEigensystem` function (I'm new to *Mathematica*). The following is my code:

```
B = ImplicitRegion[0.1*x^2 *y^2 + 1/4 (x^2 + y^2) <= 1000, 
                   {{x, -10000, 10000}, {y, -10000, 10000}}];
NDEigensystem[-D[ψ[x, y], {x, 2}] - D[ψ[x, y], {y, 2}] + 
              ((1/4)*(x^2 + y^2) + 0.1*x^2*y^2)*ψ[x, y], 
              ψ[x, y], {x, y} ∈ B, 400]
```

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in **Details** section of `NeumannValue`:

> When no boundary condition is specified on a part of the boundary $∂Ω$, then the flux term $∇·(-c ∇u-α u+γ)+…$ over that part is taken to be `f = f + 0 = f + NeumannValue[0, …]`, so not specifying a boundary condition at all is equivalent to specifying a Neumann 0 condition.

So you don't need to explicitly set boundary condition in this case, Neumann 0 condition will be automatically used by `NDEigensystem`.

"What if I want a Neumann non-zero condition?" Please notice eigenvalue problem is well-defined only for homogeneous b.c., if you're confused about this, check e.g. [this note](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/bvpevals.aspx).